# NoSuchFileException: /usr/share/java/etc/webdefault.xml when running jetty 9 server in Intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jetty-9

My computer is:

```
Debian Buster

jetty-9.4.15.v20190215

openjdk 11.0.7 2020-04-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.7+10-post-Debian-3deb10u1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.7+10-post-Debian-3deb10u1, mixed mode, sharing)

IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1.1 (Ultimate Edition)
Build #IU-201.7223.91, built on April 30, 2020
```

I installed jetty server by a command `sudo apt install jetty9`. I created a simple hello world web application as in a tutorial: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-running-your-first-java-ee-application.html

I configured the project to run with jetty server. Each time I press `run` the exception `java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /usr/share/java/etc/webdefault.xml` appears.

This is the log:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -DSTOP.PORT=0 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=/home/u/.cache/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2020.1/jetty/Jetty_9_4_15_v20190215_First-java-ee-application/jmxremote.password -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.access.file=/home/u/.cache/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2020.1/jetty/Jetty_9_4_15_v20190215_First-java-ee-application/jmxremote.access -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -DOPTIONS=jmx -javaagent:/opt/idea-IU-201.7223.91/lib/idea_rt.jar=35455:/opt/idea-IU-201.7223.91/bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /usr/share/jetty9/start.jar org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main --module=jmx /tmp/context2config/jetty-contexts.xml
Detected server http port: 8080
[2020-06-04 11:19:21,720] Artifact First-java-ee-application:war exploded: Waiting for server connection to start artifact deployment...
2020-06-04 23:19:22.847:INFO::main: Logging initialized @1174ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.StdErrLog
2020-06-04 23:19:23.028:WARN:oejx.XmlConfiguration:main: Property 'threads.min' is deprecated, use 'jetty.threadPool.minThreads' instead
2020-06-04 23:19:23.030:WARN:oejx.XmlConfiguration:main: Property 'threads.max' is deprecated, use 'jetty.threadPool.maxThreads' instead
2020-06-04 23:19:23.032:WARN:oejx.XmlConfiguration:main: Property 'threads.timeout' is deprecated, use 'jetty.threadPool.idleTimeout' instead
2020-06-04 23:19:23.234:WARN:oejx.XmlConfiguration:main: Property 'jetty.port' is deprecated, use 'jetty.http.port' instead
2020-06-04 23:19:23.234:WARN:oejx.XmlConfiguration:main: Property 'http.timeout' is deprecated, use 'jetty.http.idleTimeout' instead
STOP.PORT=33549
STOP.KEY=19labqkc4txq8
2020-06-04 23:19:23.355:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.4.15.v20190215; built: unknown; git: unknown; jvm 11.0.7+10-post-Debian-3deb10u1
2020-06-04 23:19:23.390:INFO:oejdp.ScanningAppProvider:main: Deployment monitor [file:///var/lib/jetty9/webapps/] at interval 1
2020-06-04 23:19:23.495:WARN:oejw.WebAppContext:main: Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@273444fe{root,/,file:///var/lib/jetty9/webapps/root/,UNAVAILABLE}{/root}
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /usr/share/java/etc/webdefault.xml
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:92)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:111)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:116)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:219)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:370)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:421)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider.newInputStream(FileSystemProvider.java:420)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.newInputStream(Files.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.resource.PathResource.getInputStream(PathResource.java:394)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.Descriptor.parse(Descriptor.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebDescriptor.parse(WebDescriptor.java:212)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.MetaData.setDefaults(MetaData.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebXmlConfiguration.preConfigure(WebXmlConfiguration.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.preConfigure(WebAppContext.java:506)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardStarter.processBinding(StandardStarter.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:192)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:505)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.WebAppProvider.fileAdded(WebAppProvider.java:432)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:529)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:392)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.doStart(Scanner.java:313)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.doStart(ScanningAppProvider.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.startAppProvider(DeploymentManager.java:579)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.doStart(DeploymentManager.java:240)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:415)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1572)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1512)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1511)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:220)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:490)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:77)
2020-06-04 23:19:23.507:INFO:oejdp.ScanningAppProvider:main: Deployment monitor [file:///tmp/context2deploy/] at interval 1
Connected to server
[2020-06-04 11:19:23,548] Artifact First-java-ee-application:war exploded: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
2020-06-04 23:19:23.544:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@37d4349f{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8080}
2020-06-04 23:19:23.544:INFO:oejs.Server:main: Started @1872ms
2020-06-04 23:19:23.679:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1: Stopped o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@273444fe{root,/,null,UNAVAILABLE}{/root}
2020-06-04 23:19:25.664:INFO:oeja.AnnotationConfiguration:Scanner-1: Scanning elapsed time=0ms
2020-06-04 23:19:25.755:INFO:oejshC.ROOT:Scanner-1: Warning: No org.apache.tomcat.JarScanner set in ServletContext. Falling back to default JarScanner implementation.
2020-06-04 23:19:25.850:INFO:oajs.TldScanner:Scanner-1: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
2020-06-04 23:19:25.861:INFO:oejs.session:Scanner-1: DefaultSessionIdManager workerName=node0
2020-06-04 23:19:25.861:INFO:oejs.session:Scanner-1: No SessionScavenger set, using defaults
2020-06-04 23:19:25.862:INFO:oejs.session:Scanner-1: node0 Scavenging every 660000ms
2020-06-04 23:19:25.893:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:Scanner-1: Started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@7850add7{/,file:///home/u/Dropbox/IdeaProjects/First-java-ee-application/out/artifacts/First_java_ee_application_war_exploded/,AVAILABLE}
[2020-06-04 11:19:26,386] Artifact First-java-ee-application:war exploded: Artifact is deployed successfully
[2020-06-04 11:19:26,387] Artifact First-java-ee-application:war exploded: Deploy took 2,838 milliseconds
2020-06-04 23:19:27.388:WARN:oejs.session:qtp990355670-23: Problem checking if id F8AC12E18F0A088B1D85F8D275A4B947 is in use java.lang.NullPointerException
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Does it help if you download and unpack Jetty from archive instead?

Comment: @CrazyCoder Yes. Thank you